# What's wrong with this statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1071

```
mysql> create table newsgroup(
    ->  id integer unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->  creater integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->  coremember integer unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    ->  name varchar(300) not null unique,
    ->  description text,
    ->  created datetime not null,
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
mysql>
```

I changed `300` to `250`,and it's ok.But I don't really understand.

Comment: What is the MySQL server version?

Comment: Relative answers are [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157823/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes/6158040#6158040) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131206/mysql-key-was-too-long-issue/4139541#4139541).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database encoding is set to `UTF8`

An `UTF8` character may take up to `3` bytes in `MySQL`, so `767` bytes is `255` characters.

Creating a `UNIQUE` index on such long text fields is not recommended.

Instead, create a plain prefixed index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_newsgroup_name ON newsgroup (name (30))
```

, which is enough for the prefixed searches, and add another column to store the `MD5` hash which would ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

767 bytes is the stated prefix limititation for InnoDB tables. :)

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using utf-8 or even a heavier charset and thus every symbol is represented by one, two, three or four bytes. In MySQL `utf8` stands for max 3-byte sequence, and [`utf8mb4`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) for max 4-byte sequence.

Answer (score -1):

remove UNIQUE from the varchar.